# how to use relative path in taglib Sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, path

I use TagLib# for getting properties from mp3 Files .
But when I set relative path , I getting  this ERROR :

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\statics\File\110-7a3465.mp3'.
```

**My path is :'/statics\File\110-7a3465.mp3'.**

Path retrive from data base .

when I use absolute path its ok .

I use ASP.NET 
How can I do this ?